# "Налет" и "набег"

Tags: семантика

В кроссворде попался вопрос, куда подходили "налет" и "набег", после чего я задумалась, есть ли разница в значении этих двух слов. Насколько я понимаю, оба слова описывают внезапное нападение. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Налет и набег имеют как сходство, так и различие в значениях. Сходство – это неожиданность и стремительность, динамика которых связана со значением  глаголов "лететь и бежать". Различие в цели, масштабности, способе осуществления и в области применения.

Набеги совершались в определенную историческую эпоху на какую-л. территорию с целью грабежа, опустошения, захвата в плен: "Их сёла и нивы за буйный набег Обрёк он мечам и пожарам" (Пушкин). Это было действительное перемещение пеших или конных  отрядов, иногда значительных.

Налет – современное понятие.  Это также неожиданное нападение, но  обычно  локального характера (бандитский налет на банк). Кроме того, налетом называют неожиданное массированное нападение  авиации, что определяется прямым значением глагола "летать".

Comment: Спасибо, София!

Comment: София ,как всегда , пунктуальна и мудра . Но хочу дополнить , что НАЛЁТом в русском фольклоре называли также и огненных змеев (есть  мнение , что таковыми воспринимали шаровую молнию) .